# how to remove first and last double quotes in a json string in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, string

I want to remove first and last double quotes in my json string.

```
"[{\"CircleID\":1,\"CircleName\":\"Andhra Pradesh\"},{\"CircleID\":4,\"CircleName\":\"Assam\"},{\"CircleID\":5,\"CircleName\":\"Bihar\"},{\"CircleID\":6,\"CircleName\":\"Chennai\"},{\"CircleID\":7,\"CircleName\":\"Delhi\"},{\"CircleID\":8,\"CircleName\":\"Gujarat\"},{\"CircleID\":9,\"CircleName\":\"Himachal Pradesh\"},{\"CircleID\":10,\"CircleName\":\"Haryana\"},{\"CircleID\":17,\"CircleName\":\"Mumbai\"},{\"CircleID\":26,\"CircleName\":\"Jharkhand\"},{\"CircleID\":27,\"CircleName\":\"Chhattisgarh\"}]"
```

in above json string I want to remove first and last double quotes.how to remove.Iam tried but no use. Iam using string.replce method,string.trim() method but quotes are not removed.please help me.

Comment: have you tried `Trim()`

Comment: remember that `Trim` and `Replace` are returning new string, not modifying existing one

Comment: @un-lucky yes I tried

Comment: Are you sure the string actually contains those quotes, or is this just the way it's written in the source? When debugging, what does `stringname[0]` say? I'm asking, because I also see `\"` to denote quotes inside the string...

Comment: If you are doing that to make this string valid json, it won't help. But otherwise just Trim and note wudzik's comment. And if you get that from Visual Studio, it's not actually what's in the string.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding something. the way you define string in `""` doesn't mean it have double quotes at first and last. so `""` is actually empty.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) do not forget to assign the result back to string variable. string in c# are immutable and we need to assign the changed value back to the variable.

```
jsonStr = jsonStr.Trim( '"' );
```

If you have multiple characters you can use overloaded [String.Trim(Char[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
jsonStr = jsonStr.Trim( new Char[] { '"' } );
```

**Edit** in OP there is only on double quote in beginning and end of string but if we have multiple double quotes in beginning and end and we just want to remove only first and last then we can use `string.Substring`

```
jsonStr = jsonStr.Substring(1, jsonStr.Length-2);
```

Comment: Note you don't have to new up a `char[]` since `Trim` uses params. So you could write it as `jsonStr = jsonStr.Trim('"');`

Comment: Thanks @AshBurlaczenko

Comment: @CodesInChaos, do you mean, string str = "\""; would fail with str = str.Trim( '"' );?

Comment: Trimming that would remove all `"`, instead of just the first and the last one.

Comment: It will remove all `"` from beginning and end but not inside string. I think it wont have problem with given sample. But it could be further refined if required using Substring.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You are one of those who would reason that 1 is not a prime number, right? Because it is not divisible by.. never mind.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `"` and `\"` are actually in the string, and not an artifact of embedding that string in source code or displaying it in the debugger.

In that case, you don't want to just remove the initial and trailing `"`, but you need to treat it as a json string and decode it. This will also replace the encoded `\"` by plain `"` inside the string.

If you're using Newtonsoft Json:

```
decodedString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score -1):

this is help for me.

```
        responseContent = responseContent.Substring(1, responseContent.Length - 1);
        responseContent = responseContent.Substring(0, responseContent.Length - 1);
```

Comment: I'd use `Substring(1, length - 2)` instead